# why am I getting unused argument using c in r?

Tags: r, vectorization

When I try:

`x=c(1,2,3)`

...I get the message `unused argument (3)`

When I type `x=c(1,2)` it takes the function but when I type `x` it gives me a value of `[3]`. I want to create a simple vector of numbers but I don't know why it is giving me this message.

Comment: Type `c` and press "ENTER".  If you don't see `function (...)  .Primitive("c")`, use the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I presume you created a user-defined function called `c`, thereby replacing the built-in base-r function. Try `rm("c")` and then everything should work as expected again.